# How to export non-standard include directories in catkin?

Tags: robotic-arm, catkin, include, tinyxml, cross-compiling

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This question spawned from question 68680.

I'm using yujin_tools to cross-compile ROS for ARM.  I've created a Catkin package for tinyxml that installs headers to /include/tinyxml, and the package advertises "include" and "include/tinyxml" in the catkin_package() macro.

When I build rospack, it complains about not finding the tinyxml.h header:

```
/home/user/ros_yujin_ws/src/rospack/src/rospack.cpp:30: fatal error: tinyxml.h: No such file or directory
```

rospack is using the non-namespaced version of the tinyxml include directive, but I've installed them namespaced.  How do I tell rospack to look in /include/tinyxml instead of or in addition to /include?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/93266/how-to-export-non-standard-include-directories-in-catkin?/) by [dustingooding](https://answers.ros.org/users/3314/dustingooding/) on ROS Answers with karma: 139 on 2013-10-22

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So catkin makes the assumption that you install all of your headers into the root of the include folder, i.e. `<prefix>/include`, when generating your CMake config file and pkg-config files. So your resulting `pkg_name_INCLUDE_DIRS` will by default be `<prefix>/include`. In this instance you want to have that also include `<prefix>/include/pkg_name` as well.

There are two ways to accomplish this. The first is simple, but will break if you relocate the installed package.

Simply pass this to your `catkin_package(...)` call:

```
catkin_package(
  INCLUDE_DIRS include include/tinyxml ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/include/tinyxml
  ...
)
```

The second way uses the `pkg_name_DIR` variable which allows you to make a relocatable addition to your `_INCLUDE_DIRS`. The problem is that this variable is not available in your `CMakeLists.txt`, but is available when your package is `find_package`'ed, so you have to use a CMake extras file (which gets evaluated at `find_package` time) in order to do this correctly.

Reference: http://docs.ros.org/api/catkin/html/dev_guide/generated_cmake_api.html#catkin_package (`CFG_EXTRAS`)

In order to do this, what you will want to do is to is create a file in your project `cmake/<pkg_name>-extras.cmake.in` where you replace `<pkg_name>` with your package name. In that file you should do something like this:

```
list(APPEND @PROJECT_NAME@_INCLUDE_DIRS "${@PROJECT_NAME@_DIR}/../../../@CATKIN_GLOBAL_INCLUDE_DESTINATION@/tinyxml")
```

The elements inside of `@..@` will get templated at build time of your package. You will need to tell catkin to do this templating for you:

```
catkin_package(
  ...
  CFG_EXTRAS <pkg_name>-extras.cmake
)
```

Note that you do not include the `.in` extension here.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2013-10-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 8

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2013-10-22**:
@Dirk Thomas please review this answer

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2013-10-22**:
Looks all good to me. Great answer.

**Comment by [hawesie](https://answers.ros.org/users/246/hawesie/) on 2014-10-28**:
When doing this for a package to be released, should the <pkg_name>-extras.cmake file be installed? I'm guessing yes.

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2014-10-28**:
When you use CFG_EXTRAS the file gets installed automatically.

**Comment by [hawesie](https://answers.ros.org/users/246/hawesie/) on 2014-10-28**:
Awesome, thanks.